# Trying to understand the asymptotic cases involved with O(M+N)

Tags: math, time-complexity, runtime, big-o, complexity-theory

If O(M) is same as O(N) then O(N+M) handles that, but if O(M) is greater than O(N), how does O(M+N) handle that case to be where it equal to O(M), and vice versa? Also when would there be a situation with two arguments being passed in the code where O(M) is greater than O(N) or O(N) is greater than O(M)?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to ask. What do you mean by *"handle"*? If an algorithm has multiple inputs, it is natural do state its runtime as a function of both. Typical examples are graph algorithms that usually depend on the number of vertices and the number of edges.

Comment: I read online how if M>N, then O(M+N) is equal to O(M), and vice versa, but I am having trouble understanding how is that possible?

Comment: Then let's do a graph example. Your algorithm is BFS, which has a time complexity of `O(V + E)`, where `V` is the number of vertices and `E` is the number of edges. You use that algorithm to solve another problem, where you have `n` people. You represent each of these people with a node (hence `V = n`) and connect each peson with every second person (hence, `E = O(n^2)`). Now, when you run your algorithm, you get `O(V + E) = O(n + n^2) = O(n^2) = O(E)`.

Comment: If N<M, then M + N < 2M. i.e. less than a constant multiplied by M.